# Lower $L^1$ norm estimates of null average trigonometric polynomials depending on the order of the polynomial

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, trigonometric-sums, trigonometric-polynomials

Let $p(x)=\sum_{k=1}^m [a_k\cos(n_kx)+b_k\sin(n_kx)]$ be a null average trigonometric polynomial (null average means that is $\int_\mathbb T p =0$ or, equivalently, there are no $a_0$ and $b_0$). Denote with $N$ the order of $p$, namely the number of times that $(a_k,b_k)\neq(0,0)$. We assume that $\int_\mathbb T p^2=1$.

I have done some numerical computations and I think the following may be true, there is an optimal constant $C(N)>0$ depending only on $N$, such that

$$\frac12\|p\|_{L^1(\mathbb T)}=\int\limits_{\{p>0\}\cap\mathbb T} p(s)\,ds=-\int\limits_{\{p<0\}\cap\mathbb T} p(s)\,ds\geq C(N).$$

The optimal $C(N)$ actually exists, but I am interested in an explicit expression or a way to find $C(N)$. When $N=2$ clearly the equality holds and $C(2)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. Thank you.

Comment: Fejer kernel is one of the most basic examples of non-negative trigonometric polynomials. For those, it is clear that the middle equality cannot hold.

Comment: @Itay Fejer kernel is not null average, $n_0$ is allowed to be zero or, in other words, $\int_\mathbb T F_n\neq 0$.

Comment: You can get some lower bound by using the normalized Dirichlet kernel. Take $p(x)=D(x)-1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}(\sum_{|k|<n}e^{ikx}-1)$. It is easy to see that this polynomial is null average and is positive on the interval $I=(-\frac{c}{n},\frac{c}{n})$, with some positive constant $c$. A direct computation gives $\intop_{\{p>0\}\cap \mathbb{T}} p(x)dx>\intop_{I} p(x)dx>\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $C>0$ is some absolute constant. My feeling is that you cannot do much better.

Comment: In that case, it is even better to use the Nikolskii inequalty $2\int_{\mathbb{\{p>0\}}\cap \mathbb T}p= \int_{\mathbb T}|p|\geq \frac1{2\sqrt n}$ where $n$ is de degree of $p$. But this estimate is far from being optimal. For example, when $N=2$ and $n$ is big, this lower bound is telling nothing.

Comment: You can easily get $\int|p|^4\le 2N$ whence, by Holder, you still have $C(N)\approx N^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Yes @fedja, you are all right. in fact it is possible to compute (inefficiently) with calculus the extreme value of $\int |p|^4$, lets call it $C'(N)$. This $C'$ depends just on N, but is far from optimal.

Comment: Not too far: just give or take a factor of $5$ (unless you want to fix the spectrum, in which case you can even have a constant in some cases). How close do you really want to be to the true minimum? To find an exact value may be just beyond human reach (though, of course, it exists).